# HttpServletRequest's body is empty when war is deployed to AWS

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-glass

I'm seeing inconsistency in behavior of my code when running on my local machine v.s. AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The code is to receive notification from Google Glass.

The code snippet looks like the following:

```
public class NotifyServlet extends HttpServlet implements WeiboConstants{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(NotifyServlet.class.getSimpleName());

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Respond with OK and status 200 in a timely fashion to prevent redelivery
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        Writer writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.append("OK");
        writer.close();

        LOG.info("perpare reading");

        BufferedReader notificationReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
        String notificationString = "";

        LOG.info("begin reading ");
        // Count the lines as a very basic way to prevent Denial of Service attacks
        int lines = 0;
        while (notificationReader.ready()) {
            LOG.info("reading");
            notificationString += notificationReader.readLine();
            lines++;

            // No notification would ever be this long. Something is very wrong.
            if (lines > 1000) {
                throw new IOException("Attempted to parse notification payload that was unexpectedly long.");
            }
        }

        LOG.info("got raw notification " + notificationString);

        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
```

Google's server will do POST, which is registered separately:

```
Subscription subscription = MirrorClient.insertSubscription(credential, "https://mirrornotifications.appspot.com/forward?url=http://foo.elasticbeanstalk.com/notify", userId,
                        "timeline");
```

When testing on my local machine, I ran **mvn jetty:run** and change `foo` in above code to `my ip address:8080`.

I can receive notification from google:

{ "collection": "timeline", "itemId": "5cbf8f54-822d-4a8e-9a9f-508687bbb9e2", "operation": "INSERT", "userToken": "105242333117256730066", "userActions": [  {   "type": "LAUNCH"  } ]}

But when I packaged the war (mvn war:war) and deployed to AWS, I can see from the log that it was successfully registered with Google, and I'm getting a **POST** from Google on /notify, but it seems like the body is empty as shown in the follow log:

```
Dec 06, 2013 5:01:55 AM com.google.glassware.NotifyServlet doPost
INFO: perpare reading
Dec 06, 2013 5:01:55 AM com.google.glassware.NotifyServlet doPost
INFO: begin reading 
Dec 06, 2013 5:01:55 AM com.google.glassware.NotifyServlet doPost
INFO: got raw notification 
Dec 06, 2013 5:01:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [notify] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no JSON input found
```

How can I debug further?

**UPDATE**

I deployed the same war file to a server running Jetty instead of Tomcat, and it works fine, seems to be a Tomcat specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

To debug further you can try to post the notification directly to `http://foo.elasticbeanstalk.com/notify`

If that results in the same behavior, I would have a closer look at `BufferedReader.ready()` as the loop condition.

`ready()` is a non-blocking method. It means that if for some reason the instance of `BufferedReader` is not ready to return the data right away, then the method will immediately return false and the loop will be skipped altogether.

Then the next step in the debugging would be to comment out `ready()` and go directly with blocking `readLine()` to confirm that your servlet receives the payload.

**Update**

It seems that Jetty and Tomcat have different implementations for BufferedReader.ready() indeed.

Here's the related Stack Overflow question I found after further research: [BufferedReader ready method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510690/bufferedreader-ready-method)

Comment: Thanks Andrey - I did try POST myself instead of receiving it from Google and this still repros. I will do more investigation and report back.

Comment: Actually, have a look at this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510690/bufferedreader-ready-method